# Angle between vectors in triangle

Tags: optimization, triangles

I have three points $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ which form a triangle.
The triangle is defined as follows:

$$
  \Delta = \{\lambda_1 a_1 + \lambda_2 a_2 + \lambda_3 a_3 \mid 0 \leq \lambda_i,\; \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i = 1\}
$$

Now let $x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$ be a point such that the sum of the distances between $x$ and $a_i$ is minimal, i.e.
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^3 |x - a_i| = c
$$

[image: Little sketch]

Forgive me if this little sketch is inaccurate. So intuitively I assumed that $x$ will always be the point where all "height lines" of the $a_i$ intersect.

Thus we get

$$
\begin{align*}
  |x - a_i| &= \lvert\begin{pmatrix} x_1 - a_{i_x} \\ x_2 - a_{i_y} \end{pmatrix}\rvert \\
  &= \sqrt{(x_1 - a_{i_x})^2 + (x_2 - a_{i_y})^2}
\end{align*}
$$

where $x$ needs to be in the set $\Delta$.

Now the question is,

- How can I prove $x$ will always be this point and
- How can I prove that the angle between neighboring vectors $a_i - x$ is *always* $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$

Comment: Differences or distances?

Comment: Distances, right.

Comment: [Fermat point / Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point#Lagrange_multipliers) seems to be the easiest way.